# how to get event.detail values from combobox multipicklist using LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, event, lightning-combobox

multiSelectcombobox HTML :

```
    <template>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
      <label if:true={label} class="slds-form-element__label">
        <abbr if:true={required} title="required" class="slds-required">*</abbr>
        {label}</label
      >
      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <div class="slds-combobox_container">
          <div
            class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-picklist multi-select-combobox__dropdown"
          >
            <div class="slds-combobox_form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
              <input
                class="slds-combobox__input multi-select-combobox__input"
                aria-controls="multi-pick-list-dropdown-items"
                role="textbox"
                type="text"
                value={selectedItems}
                required={required}
                disabled={isDisabled}
                readonly
              />
              <span
                class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-down slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right multi-select-combobox__icon"
                title="Click to open the dropdown"
              >
                <lightning-icon
                  icon-name="utility:down"
                  size="xx-small"
                  alternative-text="Click here"
                  class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default"
                >
                </lightning-icon>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid multi-select-combobox__listbox"
              role="listbox"
            >
              <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                <template for:each={currentOptions} for:item="item">
                  <c-multi-select-combobox-item key={item.value} item={item} onchange={handleChange}>
                  </c-multi-select-combobox-item> 
                </template>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div if:true={hasPillsEnabled}>
        <lightning-pill-container
          if:true={isVisible}
          items={selectedOptions}
          variant="bare"
          onitemremove={handleRemove}
        ></lightning-pill-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

multi select combobox JS :

```
renderedCallback() {

    if (!this.isInitialized) {
      this.template.querySelector('.multi-select-combobox__input').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        this.handleClick(event.target);
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
      this.template.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
      document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.close();
      });
      this.isInitialized = true;
      this.setSelection();
    }
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.change(event);
  }
  handleRemove(event) {
    this.selectedOptions.splice(event.detail.index, 1);
    this.change(event);
  }
  handleClick() {
    // initialize picklist options on first click to make them editable
    if (this.isLoaded === false) {
      this.currentOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options));
      this.isLoaded = true;
    }
    console.log('Firas04',this.currentOptions);
    if (this.template.querySelector('.slds-is-open')) {
      this.close();
    } else {
      this.template.querySelectorAll('.multi-select-combobox__dropdown').forEach((node) => {
        node.classList.add('slds-is-open');
      });
    }
  }
  change(event) {
    // remove previous selection for single select picklist
    let xxx;
    if (this.singleSelect) {
      this.currentOptions.forEach((item) => (item.selected = false));
    }
    // set selected items
    this.currentOptions
      .filter((item) => item.value === event.detail.item.value)
      .forEach((item) => (item.selected = event.detail.selected));
    this.setSelection();
    
    const selection = this.getSelectedItems();
    this.passvalues = selection.map((selected) => selected.label).join(', ');
    console.log('selection CHANGEE',this.passvalues);
    
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: this.singleSelect ? selection[0] : selection }));
    // for single select picklist close dropdown after selection is made
    if (this.singleSelect) {
      this.close();
    }
  }
  close() {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('.multi-select-combobox__dropdown').forEach((node) => {
      node.classList.remove('slds-is-open');
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close'));
  }
  setSelection() {
    const selectedItems = this.getSelectedItems();
    let selection = '';
    if (selectedItems.length < 1) {
      selection = this.placeholder;
      this.selectedOptions = [];
    }  else {
      selection = selectedItems.map((selected) => selected.label).join(', ');
      this.selectedOptions = this.getSelectedItems();
    }
    this.selectedItems = selection;
    this.isVisible = this.selectedOptions && this.selectedOptions.length > 0;
    console.log('selection',selection);

  }

  getSelectedItems() {
    return this.currentOptions.filter((item) => item.selected);
  }
```

MultiSelectComboboxItem Js :

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class MultiSelectComboboxItem extends LightningElement {
  @api item;

  connectedCallback () {
    this._item =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify (this.item));
}
  get itemClass() {
    return `slds-listbox__item ${this.item.selected ? 'slds-is-selected' : ''}`;
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('change', {
        detail: { item: this.item, selected: !this.item.selected }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Parent component Js :

```
@wire( getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD } )
    picklistValues;
       handleValueChange(event) {
            const { index, field } = event.target.dataset;
            var value =    event.detail.childfilter || event.target.value  || event.detail;
            this.caseDefaultData[index][field] = value;
            
            if(event.detail != null){
            this.selectedOptions = event.detail.value;
           
            
            console.log( 'Helloooo this.selectedOptions000', JSON.stringify(this.selectedOptions) );
        }
        
            if ( event.target.dataset.id == 'fielD' && value == 'Contact') {
                value = event.detail.childfilter ;
               // this.showLookupSearch = true;
                this.caseDefaultData[index]['lookupContact']=true;
                this.input4 = 'Account';          
           //     console.log('VALUEE',value);
               
            }
            
           else if ( event.target.dataset.id == 'fielD' && value == 'AccountId') {
                value = event.detail.childfilter ;
               // this.showLookupSearch = true;
                this.caseDefaultData[index]['showLookupSearch']=true;
                this.caseDefaultData[index]['lookupContact']=false;
                this.input4 = 'Account';          
           //     console.log('VALUEE',value);
               
            }else if(event.target.dataset.id == 'fielD' && value != 'AccountId') {
                
                if(event.target.dataset.id == 'fielD' && value == 'Status'  ){
                    console.log( 'Helloooo' );
                   
                    
                   value = JSON.stringify(event.target.value) ;
                   console.log( 'Helloooo vvv',value );
                   this.caseDefaultData[index]['showLookupSearch']=false;
                   this.caseDefaultData[index]['picklistField']=true;
                    console.log( 'this.showLookupSearch',this.showLookupSearch );
                   
                    console.log( 'this.picklistField',this.picklistField );
                } else {
                    this.caseDefaultData[index]['showLookupSearch']=false;
                    this.caseDefaultData[index]['picklistField']=false;
                    this.caseDefaultData[index]['lookupContact']=false;
                    value = event.target.value ;

                   
                }
            

            }
```

Parent HTML :

```
 <template for:each={caseDefaultData}  for:item="acc"  for:index="index">
                            <tr key={acc.index} id={acc.index} > 
                                <td>Filtre #{acc.rowNumber}</td>   
                                <td>
                                    <lightning-combobox 
                                    data-index={index}
                                    data-field="Field__c"
                                    data-id="fielD"
                                    name="input1" 
                                    label="Field"
                                    placeholder="Sélectionner un champ" 
                                    value={acc.Field__c} 
                                    onchange={handleValueChange} 
                                    options={Options}>
                                    </lightning-combobox>
                                </td>
                                 
                                
                                <td style="padding-top:40px">  <lightning-input-field data-field="Operator__c" data-index={index} data-id={acc.index} field-name="Operator__c" value={acc.Operator__c} name="input2" onchange={handleValueChange} ></lightning-input-field></td>
                                
                               <template  if:true={acc.lookupContact}>
                                    <td> showLookupSearch = {acc.showLookupSearch} picklistField = {acc.picklistField} <c-lookup-search data-field="Value__c"   value={acc.Value__c}   selectedsobject="Contact" onsearchstringvaluechange={handleValueChange}    data-index={index} data-id={acc.index} label="Custom Lookup - Account"   selected-name={acc.Value__c}  recordlimit="10" onlookupselect={handlelookupselectaccount} ></c-lookup-search>  </td>
                                </template>
                               
                                <template  if:false={acc.lookupContact}>
                                    <template  if:true={acc.showLookupSearch}>
                                        <td> showLookupSearch = {acc.showLookupSearch} picklistField = {acc.picklistField} <c-lookup-search data-field="Value__c"   value={acc.Value__c}   selectedsobject="Account" onsearchstringvaluechange={handleValueChange}    data-index={index} data-id={acc.index} label="Custom Lookup - Account"   selected-name={acc.Value__c}  recordlimit="10" onlookupselect={handlelookupselectaccount} ></c-lookup-search>  </td>
                                    </template>
                                        <template  if:false={acc.showLookupSearch}>
                                            <template  if:true={acc.picklistField}>
                                                <template  if:true={picklistValues.data}>
                                                    <td> showLookupSearch = {acc.showLookupSearch}   picklistField = {acc.picklistField} {acc.Value__c}    <c-multi-select-combobox
                                                        label="Options01"
                                                        name="options01"
                                                        options={picklistValues.data.values}
                                                        onchange={handleValueChange}  data-field="Value__c" data-index={index}  value={acc.Value__c}  data-id={acc.index} 
                                                      ></c-multi-select-combobox> </td>
                                                </template>
                                            </template>
                                            <template  if:false={acc.picklistField}>
                                                <td>showLookupSearch = {acc.showLookupSearch}   picklistField = {acc.picklistField} <lightning-input type="text"   data-field="Value__c" data-index={index} data-id={acc.index} label="Value" value={acc.Value__c} onchange={handleValueChange} ></lightning-input>   </td>
                                            </template>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
```

So the combobox is showing status picklist field with multi select , but i can't understand why  `this.selectedOptions`  is showing `undefined` , the `event.detail` is showing well the attributes ..

The output of  *this.selectedOptions = event.detail;*  :

[image]

According to David solution :

i have changed the name of event as : `this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change011', { detail: this.singleSelect ? selection[0] : selection }));`  and in the parent html :  `c-multi-select-combobox label="Options01" name="options01" options={picklistValues.data.values} onchange={handleValueChange} onchange011={handleValueChange}`  but the event.detail.value is still undefined

[image]

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format _all_ of your code blocks. You can also use triple backticks (```) before and after each block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using custom events that share the names of standard events (like `change`) can produce surprising behavior, like you see here. That's because your handler `handleValueChange()` is *also* receiving plain old `onchange` events that bubble up from the `<input>` element (and potentially other elements within your component). Those standard events do not have a `detail` property, which nets you an `undefined` value.

There are two obvious ways to fix this issue:

- Use a custom event that is not named `change`.
- In your multi-select component, catch the `change` events from your embedded components and call `event.stopPropagation()` on them, to prevent your own parent component from receiving those events.

---

It appears that your code is also assuming that change events come from a single-select picklist:

```
this.selectedOptions = event.detail.value;
```

Your component sets `event.detail` to an array in the multi-select case:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: this.singleSelect ? selection[0] : selection }));
```

which doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: David , i have update the parent component code - i don't think the problem is related  the name of event *change* because `event.detail` is showing attributes , but the value is undefined ..

Comment: @Farkous He's correct. Using a standard event name causes things to behave badly. I first discovered this myself earlier in 2022. If you want to use a standard event like change, you have to do `document.createEvent("htmlevents")`, and set the properties.

Comment: How to solve my issue ? i have changed the calling in *MultiSelectCombobox*  `this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change011', { detail: this.singleSelect ? selection[0] : selection }));` and in the parent HTML : `<c-multi-select-combobox onchange={handleValueChange} change011=={handleValueChange}`  JS : `handleChange00(event) {
          this.selectedOptions = event.detail;
          this.selectedOptions =  event.detail.map((selected) => selected.label).join(', ');
        }
        handleValueChange(event) {
            this.selectedOptions = event.detail.value;
        }` its still un

Comment: Your parent HTML is not valid. Event handlers need `on` and do not use `==`.

Comment: Yes i know i have corrected it but the `this.selectedOptions` it still undefined

Comment: Well, you're still catching `change` events, which - as discussed above - don't have a `detail` property at all. However, I think there's a second bug, which I note above in an edit.